# Error for '__aeabi_STH' when I build simple kernel with Makefile

Tags: linux, build, makefile

Now, I'm trying to make a simple kernel which just print "Hello world" after booting.

I want to use arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8,

so I write Makefile like this

```
CC = arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8
LD = arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld
OC = arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy

#CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
#LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
#OC = arm-none-eabi-objcopy

CFLAGS  = -nostdinc -I. -I../include
CFLAGS += -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 
CFLAGS += -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -pipe #-mapcs-32
CFLAGS += -mcpu=xscale -msoft-float -fno-builtin #-mshort-load-bytes

LDFLAGS = -static -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -p -X -T ./main-ld-script

OCFLAGS = -O binary -R .note -R .comment -S

all: karlinux.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o entry.o entry.S
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o gpio.o gpio.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o time.o time.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o vsprintf.o vsprintf.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o printf.o printf.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o string.o string.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o serial.o serial.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o lib1funcs.o lib1funcs.S
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o karlinux.o karlinux.c
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o karlinux_elf entry.o gpio.o time.o vsprintf.o printf.o string.o serial.o lib1funcs.o karlinux.o
    $(OC) $(OCFLAGS) karlinux_elf karlinux_img

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm karlinux_elf
    rm karlinux_img
```

However, I got an error when LD does something.

Error message is

```
xaliver@ubuntu:~/Documents/Karlinux/Karlinux/main$ make
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 -c -nostdinc -I. -I../include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -pipe  -mcpu=xscale -msoft-float -fno-builtin  -o entry.o entry.S
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 -c -nostdinc -I. -I../include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -pipe  -mcpu=xscale -msoft-float -fno-builtin  -o gpio.o gpio.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 -c -nostdinc -I. -I../include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -pipe  -mcpu=xscale -msoft-float -fno-builtin  -o time.o time.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 -c -nostdinc -I. -I../include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -pipe  -mcpu=xscale -msoft-float -fno-builtin  -o vsprintf.o vsprintf.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 -c -nostdinc -I. -I../include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -pipe  -mcpu=xscale -msoft-float -fno-builtin  -o printf.o printf.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 -c -nostdinc -I. -I../include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -pipe  -mcpu=xscale -msoft-float -fno-builtin  -o string.o string.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 -c -nostdinc -I. -I../include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -pipe  -mcpu=xscale -msoft-float -fno-builtin  -o serial.o serial.c
serial.c:26:0: warning: "__REG" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define __REG(x) (x) 
 ^
In file included from serial.c:18:0:
../include/pxa255.h:46:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define __REG(x)   (*((volatile Word *) io_p2v (x))) 
 ^
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 -c -nostdinc -I. -I../include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -pipe  -mcpu=xscale -msoft-float -fno-builtin  -o lib1funcs.o lib1funcs.S
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 -c -nostdinc -I. -I../include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -pipe  -mcpu=xscale -msoft-float -fno-builtin  -o karlinux.o karlinux.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld -static -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -p -X -T ./main-ld-script -o karlinux_elf entry.o gpio.o time.o vsprintf.o printf.o string.o serial.o lib1funcs.o karlinux.o
time.o: In function `SetWatchdog':
time.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `__aeabi_idiv'
vsprintf.o: In function `number':
vsprintf.c:(.text+0x18e): undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
vsprintf.c:(.text+0x1a4): undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidivmod'
vsprintf.c:(.text+0x22a): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
vsprintf.c:(.text+0x230): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
printf.o: In function `printf':
printf.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
printf.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Does anybody know how to link those function?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you and I have same book.

ARM architecture doesn't have 'divide' instruction, so when compiler (gcc cross compiler) encounter division instruction like '1/2', then converted to function like '__aeabi_uidiv()', '__aeabi_uidivmod()', etc.

When your linker 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld' processes linking, linker try to find library that include __aeabi_uidiv' function (and other functions). This library is libgcc.a, but you specify option '-nostdlib -nodefaultlib' so linker cannot find __aeabi_uidiv()' function's main body. Linking fails.

In my opinion, the author's intention is such translation function __aeabi_uidiv() is included in lib1funcs.s. Toolchain that is included in the book is gcc-3.3.2. That version of gcc arm cross compiler translate division into '__udivsi3()' function, instead '__aeabi_uidiv()'. And '__udivsi3()' function implementation is included in 'lib1funcs.s'.

In conclusion, solution is two.

1. use toolchain of gcc-3.3.2, instead yours. **(recommended)**
2. change name '__udivsi3()' and '__udivsi3...()' in 'lib1funcs.s' file  to '__aeabi_uidiv()' '__aeabi_uidiv...()'

I tried second method and succeeded, but this 'undefined reference to...' problem shows up in book's next examples again and makes me crazy. To succeed in second's method, I think relative deeper understanding of compile and linking process is needed. I recommend first method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will do the first method.